# I can't seem to troubleshoot this code( python crash course)

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Python and Django in particular and I"m working my way through the Python Crash Course(1st ed) book by Eric Matthes. Everything has been running fine up until chapter 19 when I am adding functionality for the user to add entries to topics. Basically its a web app that working kind of like a journal to log things you learn about certain topics.

I've thrown in some print statements to try and figure out where the exactly problem lies and from what I can tell it seems to be with the if statement in def new_entry function in views.py. I can't figure out where to really go from here. out of the print statements i have in the current code only the one right below the first if statement executes print("this is requesting a new form")

my views.py file with relevant entry

```
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a particular topic."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create blank form
        form = EntryForm()
        print("this is requesting a new form")
    else:
        print("else statment runs?")
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        print("The else statment is running")
        if form.is_valid():
            print("the form.is_valid function works")
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            print("new_entry saved!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic', args=[topic_id]))

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

My forms.py that contains the form

```
from django import forms

from .models import Topic, Entry


class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'test': ''}


class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

The new entry template

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>

  <p>Add a new entry:</p>
  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}" method='post'>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button name='submit'>add entry</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

I have the feeling that I'm missing something simple but and if I need to I'll add everything to a git hub repo so that you can take a look there if needed.

Comment: Hagyn's answered your immediate problem, but I'd suggest, that unless you have a really good reason to do so otherwise, you should probably take a look at class based views that've been in Django for a while now, eg: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/ - saves a lot off hassle and boilerplate coding... sounds like the book you're working through might be a little outdated...

Comment: The book does have a 2nd edition( which came out a few weeks after I bought this one) out so I'm sure that there has been changes but the author has kept things relatively updated on his site.. I'm basically just going by the book that I have for now to get some basics and some projects under my belt to feel a bit more comfortable doing this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if request != 'POST'` is not right to check if the request is not a POST one. Your if statment should be `if request.method != 'POST'`.

Check out Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method

Comment: Yep this was exactly the problem. I'd missed it when going through the code (several times). need to walk away for a few hours next time and come back fresh. Thanks!